# Where to start when designing a custom PCB as per requirements?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, wifi, camera

Before I ask this question let me tell you that I am an IT professional with little knowledge of electronics.

Here is my problem:

> I want to design such a device which will **stream video** to my mobile upon press of a button. [the button will be on the device].

> The device will have a **camera and mic**. [so the micro-controller used will need to have video streaming capabilities]

> This device will be connected to **WiFi**.

The mobile app development part of this device can be easily done.

But what do I need to read to create a design of the PCB for the requirements I just mentioned?

I am aware that I can buy CCTV for my purpose, but this is something I want to try out by myself as a DIY project.

Comment: Raspberry pi and raspberry pi cam, by the way this question is off topic

Comment: Is there some reason you really need to make your own board?  There are many available single board computers (like the Raspberry Pi) that can do the job, and probably for far less than it would cost to develope your own board and have it built.

Comment: With all due respect, you don't want to try this at your level of experience. With these data rates you'll need a multi-layer pcb, which is not a good starting project. You'd also need to learn the protocols involved in sending data to a mobie, and they are  not simple. You can't just take the output of a camera and zip it out - it needs to be formatted and packetized, and the audio data inserted as packets as well. I really suggest you try something a great deal simpler. Using a prepackaged solution is not as satisfying, but neither is failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely more involved than you think it is.

Streaming video is not trivial. In particular, streaming video with a microcontroller is not typically done, unless you are talking about very small resolutions. The throughput is simply insufficient.

To stream video, you will typically want an *applications processor*, which is a step above a microcontroller. It's a more powerful processor with heavy duty peripherals and much more RAM (you'll need quite a bit of RAM for a framebuffer). For instance, compare an [Atmel ATmega32u4](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega32u4.aspx) (a microcontroller) with a [TI AM3358](http://www.ti.com/product/AM3358) (a microprocessor). They are very different beasts. Even with a bigger microcontroller like an [ST Micro STM32F429](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f429-439.html?querycriteria=productId=LN1806) (which even has a camera interface), streaming is going to be very challenging, if it's even possible.

At a minimum, you will need an external RAM, a fast camera interface, and a fast pipe to your WiFi chipset (which is a whole other can of worms).

In short, this is a very involved project, and the board design is only part of it: you will need to do all the design work (component selection, schematic capture, layout, DFM, etc) as well as firmware development (there is quite a lot of embedded firmware required). This requires extensive knowledge of many different levels of engineering: probably MIPI for camera to processor, embedded firmware development, extensive hardware engineering know-how, network protocols and network stack development, PCB design, ....you get the point. As others have stated, you are much better off using COTS parts.

Comment: +1 for answering an essentially unanswerable question and doing it well :-).

Comment: wow, :-) really well answered. I think that solves my query for now hence marking it as correct. 

What i need to do is learn more of microcontroller programming. 
Firmware development is what will be interesting. Thanks a lot.